# Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Byte for argument #2 'target'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am running a nn on colab and came across this error which was not there when i ran the same code on my local system. I have tried with reduced batch size too but the error still persists.

```
Loading dataset
Start training
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-37432f9d142a> in <module>()
     70           start_epoch=start_epoch, log=log_interval,
     71           checkpoint_path=os.path.join(dataset_dir, "cnn_block_frame_flow"),
---> 72           validate=True, resume=False, flow=True, use_cuda=cuda)
     73 
     74     #model = models.model()

/content/KTH-Action-Recognition/main/train_helper.py in train(model, num_epochs, train_set, dev_set, lr, batch_size, start_epoch, log, checkpoint_path, validate, resume, flow, use_cuda)
    107             outputs = get_outputs(model, samples["instance"], flow=flow,
    108                                   use_cuda=use_cuda)
--> 109             loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    110             loss.backward()
    111             optimizer.step()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    487             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    488         else:
--> 489             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    490         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    491             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
    902     def forward(self, input, target):
    903         return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
--> 904                                ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
    905 
    906 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   1968     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   1969         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 1970     return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
   1971 
   1972 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   1788                          .format(input.size(0), target.size(0)))
   1789     if dim == 2:
-> 1790         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   1791     elif dim == 4:
   1792         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss2d(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)

RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Byte for argument #2 'target'
```

Can someone tell me what is causing this error? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title of your question is telling what is causing this error. The `target` should have type `torch.LongTensor`, but it is instead `torch.ByteTensor`. Before calling `nll_loss` do:

```py
target = target.type(torch.LongTensor)
```

Comment: `target` is a variable within **torch.nn.module**. so in colab where should i edit it also can i modify the type of `labels` instead?

Comment: The second argument. You haven't showed the code so I don't how do you call it there. What loss do you use? `nll_loss` or `crossentropyloss`?

Comment: I just checked the docs, yes, the actual true labels. Are you doing binary classification?

Comment: `crossentropyloss`. but why such an error in colab. I have already ran the code in my system which works fine but the train set is very small which is why i chose colabs

Comment: categorical classification infact, with 6 classes of data

Comment: I guess you are passing the wrong variable as second argument, probably something in your code differs from the version you ran on your local machine.

Comment: I modified the type and it gave me another error, this time its the loss, `print("epoch %d/%d, iteration %d/%d, loss: %s"
    112                       % (epoch, start_epoch + num_epochs - 1, i + 1,
--> 113                       len(train_set) // batch_size, loss.data[0]))

IndexError: invalid index of a 0-dim tensor. Use tensor.item() to convert a 0-dim tensor to a Python number`

Comment: just use `loss.item()`, not `loss.item(data[0])`. This one haven't worked on you local machine, otherwise you would get the same error

Comment: its working, network has started training, thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192118/discussion-between-shjk-and-vlad).